# How to Upgrade Kernel Version?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel

My question is how to upgrade kernel versions for Ubuntu 12.04?
My computer specifications are:

> Ubuntu 12.04
>   Kernel Version Linux 3.2.0-40-generic AMD Processor
>   64 bit processor.

I have checked out the link, from youtube. The video that I have found helpfully and good instructions. But I am a little sceptical if it's the right method on upgrading kernel version. [video on kernel upgrade](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=traegZveTKo)

Comment: Question: why do you want to? This is something you should normally only do if you have a problem. Reminder: 12.04 is -lts- so you use it for its stability and not for it to be bleeding edge.

Comment: For generic instructions see http://askubuntu.com/questions/379033/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-the-kernel-in-ubuntu-to-any-stable-or-testing-relea/379034#379034

Answer (score 5):

The video that you have just watched is 100% legit way of updating your kernel. To summarize things up you basically download 4 kernel files

1. Linux-image
2. Linux-image-extra
3. Linux-headers-generic

You download first 3 based on your OS bit so 32bit - i386 or 64bit - AMD64

The

- Linux-headers-all

is for both OS architecture

once you have those files downloaded you open terminal and locate files that you have just downloaded using

> cd

command and then simply execute the installation process by running

> sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb

Notice that it is good thing to remove all other .deb files from the folder that you downloading kernel files so they won't mess up during installation.

Comment: Thank Nikki, for the information that you posted. Very detailed information. Good info. Again thanks Nikki. From Ronnie Marlow